# Creating histogram with dates on x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am struggling with making a histogram where the dates are shown on the x-axis (e.g., "1 April", "1 May", "1 June", etc along the bottom)

I've tried to do something like this, but I don't know how to get the dates in the format that I need:

```r
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)

vaccination_data <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dsfsi/covid19za/master/data/covid19za_provincial_cumulative_timeline_vaccination.csv")

View(vaccination_data)
```

To omit empty values

```
vaccination_data1 <- na.omit(vaccination_data)
```

To group daily count into monthly count

```
monthly_data <- vaccination_data1
monthly_data$year <- strftime(monthly_data$date, "%y")
monthly_data$month <- strftime(monthly_data$date, "%m")
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
ggplot(vaccination_data1) +
  geom_col(aes(x = date, y =  total)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels =  "%d %b")
```

[image]